# How to get back my windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I had Windows 7 installed in my laptop, but I wanted to run Ubuntu alongside. When I tried to install it, it asked for a partition but I m not sure where it got installed. My c drive didn't have enough space ,as it contains the window 7 os, I m anxious that can it so happen that my windows 7 got removed by Ubuntu? Bt I can still see all my program files and installed softwares in my drive c. When I boot my pc I do not get any Windows 7 option.. Nd the available Ubuntu options don't run unless I have my flash drive (containing the Ubuntu iOS files) plugged into my usb. How can I get to my windows 7 and then run Ubuntu alongside? I have tried updating the grub with all the command available in various conversations, but it didnot work.. Someone please help, it's a bit complicated for me as I m a total beginner in this.. please..

Comment: Have you checked in your BIOS to see if you have a "Windows Boot Manager"  boot option that you can boot from?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a live USB flash drive that you used to install Ubuntu, you can boot from the Ubuntu live USB and run Boot Repair to repair the GRUB bootloader. Then both Ubuntu and Windows 7 will be able to boot when your flash drive is not plugged into a USB port.

From the Ubuntu live USB, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

[image]

Boot Repair is available from ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. Boot-Repair can repair boot problems in Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

if you know by a fact your windows7 and users folder were in the same partition and you can still see your files, there is a good chance your that everything is fine and you only overwrited the boot during installation in a wrong manner. try installing again paying attention to the options, click on "manual" opposed to "guided use entire disk" and choose your first hard-drive to receive the boot loader, use or create different partition or hard drive for linux instalation. the instalation should take care of putting a menu(GRUB menu) on the screen when you reboot with windows 7 and linux to be chosen from. maybe you had some error after installation that  before installing the boot loader